# Inserting query results to an existing BigQuery Table

Tags: go, google-bigquery

I have some concern regarding the `QueryConfig` in Go. It says that:

> WriteDisposition specifies how existing data in the destination table is treated. By default is WriteEmpty.

So I assume whenever the destination table exists it automatically appends the result into the existing table instead of creating a new table. However, on my side it creates a new table which is going to raise the exemption 
`tableID already exists`.

Here is my sample code:

```
ctx := context.Background()
client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
if err != nil {
   return fmt.Errorf("bigquery.NewClient: %v", err)
}
defer client.Close()
query := SELECT * FROM `projectID.datasetID.tableID`
q := client.Query(query)
q.QueryConfig.Dst = client.Dataset(datasetID).Table(tableID)
job, err := q.Run(ctx)
if err != nil {
return err
}
 status, err := job.Wait(ctx)
 if err != nil {
    return err
}
if err := status.Err(); err != nil {
   return err
}
it, err := job.Read(ctx)
```

What did I miss?

Comment: in python there is a way to set it to write disposition
`config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'` what is the golang counterpart of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer by reading the bigquery Go docs. https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#TableWriteDisposition

Added this line of code for setting the QueryConfig WriteDisposition to append data to an existing table

```
q.QueryConfig.WriteDisposition = "WRITE_APPEND"
```

Hope this helps.